# How time only updating in the stackoverflow main page?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, live-refresh

**The main Stack Overflow pages do not use live-updating; it would be too much of a performance penalty on the server due to the high volume of questions.**
This is the answer for one of my question why stackoverflow page is not getting refreshed..?
But how the times are updating?
Like 3h 3m ago , 1h 2m ago etc..
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'ago' relative times are updated by javascript, in your browser.

Each entry on the page has the *absolute* time stored as a `title` attribute, and the script just periodically updates the shown relative time relative to your computer clock:

```
<span title="2013-04-18 09:39:16Z" class="relativetime">19 mins ago</span>
```

Consequently, if you set your computer clock incorrectly, say, to a point of time in the future, these relative time indicators will be wrong too.