# Inverse Groundhog day / Website seems stuck: today (2020-12-22), the 2020-12-20 is not "yesterday"

Tags: support, bug

I was wondering why a user that asked a 22 upvotes-question had but 393 reputation; that probably is alright, but:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/204881/hermetica

shows that the question was asked "yesterday":

[image: profile screenshot]

whereas the reputation history correctly shows that the question was asked "2 days ago":

[image: activity screenshot]

So I checked the question itself, and it states it's asked "yesterday",

[image: question field screenshot]

where yesterday really seems to be an ~ 28 hours day.

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177037/how-time-only-updating-in-the-stackoverflow-main-page/177038#177038

Comment: @rene ah, interesting! That makes this a bug in the javascript I get (my computer's clock is definitely NTP-sync'ed)